# Is there a way to send a TCP request to the client through the browser?

Tags: javascript, sockets, tcp, fingerprint

I am working on a web application. I want to know certain parameters of the client's machine. I have been able to find out most of the parameters but I am struck in the following parameters.

1) TCP Timestamp

2) TCP/IP FingerPrint

So, my question is, Is there a way to send TCP request to the client through my web application(assuming I know the client's IP address). Or is there any way around to find out these parameters on the client's machine. Any hint on how to get started will be appreciated.

Comment: you can ping an http-reachable IP, but it's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: the thing is that I am working on device fingerprinting. I want to collect as much parameters as possible from the client's machine without using applet or some code that runs on the client's machine. I want to extract these parameters with the help of Javascript. So I just wanted to know if there is a way to find tcp request time through javascript ?

Comment: you can time img pings and ajax request, etc. you can get current client IP from webRTC-supporting browsers. use performance.now() for a high-rez timestamp on manual observations. performance.getEntries() also has connection details, which might save you from having to manually time, and it reports redirects, which naive img pings don't...

Answer (score 1):

> So, my question is, Is there a way to send TCP request to the client through my web application(assuming I know the client's IP address). Or is there any way around to find out these parameters on the client's machine. Any hint on how to get started will be appreciated.

If you can use sockets (not websockets) from your web application than you could try to establish a TCP connection to the client. But this will probably not work in most cases, because:

- The client will not listen for TCP connections from outside, so you would get at most a RST packet.
- Clients are mostly behind some NAT device today, like a router at home or inside a mobile network. Therefore the source IP you see from the client connection to your server is in most cases not the IP of the client itself, but of the NAT router. Since the client has no public IP address it can not be reached directly.

> 1) TCP Timestamp
>
> 2) TCP/IP FingerPrint

These are usually not parameter you find out by doing a simple TCP request, but you need to work with raw sockets. Also, part of these information can be derived from the established connection, but you must be able to track the connection on the raw level (like with tcpdump).